# Why AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to screape the youtube data from trending page. Got error

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').encode("utf-8")

csv_file = open('YouTube.csv','w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Title', 'Description'])

for content in soup.findAll('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content"):
#for content in soup.find_all('div', class_= "yt-lockup-content"):
    print (content)
```

Comment: Because `soup` is in `bytes` ? Use `BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')` instead of `BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').encode("utf-8")`. Why are you encoding it ?

Comment: If you need to encode for some reason, it should be here: `source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending").text.encode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll'** is because in your code you are doing:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').encode("utf-8")
```

What is happening is, you are converting **str** to **byte** by encoding the string. **encode** is used to convert **str** to **bytes** with the encoding of choice.

One should never be manipulating with **bytes** inside the program. Instead use the unicode sandwitch principle. Which is convert **bytes** to **str** on read, do stuff with **str**, then convert **str** to **bytes** on write to output.

So just use the **str** inside the program, instead of **bytes** like,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```